# MySQL lag column DATEDIFF

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following data:

```
CUSTOMER_ID CONTACT_ID  COMM_CREATION_DAY DAYS_SINCE_LAST_CONTACT
10000       28036173295 2014-12-21        0
10000       28365672745 2015-01-29        DATEDIFF('2015-01-29','2014-12-21')
10000       28576719155 2015-02-26        DATEDIFF('2015-02-26','2014-01-29')
38409       28432217395 2015-02-07        0
38409       28565986955 2015-02-25        DATEDIFF('2015-02-25,'2015-02-07')
```

I'm trying to get the `DAYS_SINCE_LAST_CONTACT` column, but there's no `LEAD` or `LAG` function in MySQL. How do I do this in a single `SELECT` statement?

I tried the following:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, COMM_ID , COMM_CREATION_DAY, PREVIOUS_COMM_CREATION_DAY FROM 
(
select
c.*
, @prev AS PREVIOUS_COMM_CREATION_DAY
, @prev := COMM_CREATION_DAY
FROM contacts c, (select @prev:=NULL) vars
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, c.COMM_CREATION_DAY, c.COMM_ID
) sq
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID, COMM_CREATION_DAY
```

But that gave me:

```
CUSTOMER_ID CONTACT_ID  COMM_CREATION_DAY LAST_CONTACT_DATE
10000       28036173295 2014-12-21        NULL
10000       28365672745 2015-01-29        2014-12-21
10000       28576719155 2015-02-26        2015-01-29
38409       28432217395 2015-02-07        2015-02-26 (THIS IS INCORRECT!)
38409       28565986955 2015-02-25        2015-02-07
```

Where `NULL` doesn't show up properly for the last column in all cases.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes in mysql you need to use user defined variables for such calculations something as

```
select
customer_id,
contact_id,
contact_date,
DAYS_SINCE_LAST_CONTACT 
from(
  select
  customer_id,
  contact_id,
  contact_date,
  @diff:= if(@prev_customer = customer_id,datediff(contact_date,@prev_date),0) as DAYS_SINCE_LAST_CONTACT,
  @prev_customer:=customer_id,
  @prev_date:= contact_date
  from customer c,(select @prev_customer:=0,@prev_date:=null)x
  order by customer_id,contact_date
)x
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cb9f/2